# Why is it saying that USER_SETUP is a unused varible when it's not? DISCORD.PY

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello I'm trying to make a reaction role bot, but I ran into this error. It says that my variable called USER_SETUP is unused but it's not. I have tried most things but I can't seem to get it right. Heres my code:

```
USER_DOING_SETUP = False
USER_SETUP = 0

@client.command(aliases=['rr', 'reactionroles'])
async def reactionrole(ctx, user, arg):
    if arg == "setup":
        if USER_DOING_SETUP == False:
            userId = user.id
            USER_SETUP = userId
            USER_DOING_SETUP = True
            await ctx.send(f"TEST REACTION ROLES TYPE {BOT_PREFIX}!rr cancel TO CANCEL")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Setup is used by another user")
    elif arg == "cancel":
        USER_DOING_SETUP = True
        USER_SETUP = 0
        await ctx.send("setup was cancled :)")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:
        if USER_DOING_SETUP == False:
            await message.channel.send("false")
        elif USER_DOING_SETUP == True:
            if USER_SETUP == message.author.id:
                await message.channel.send("true")
            else:
                await message.channel.send("false")
```

Error:
`Unused variable 'USER_SETUP'`

Comment: Because it's a local variable that you set and never use? Did you mean to have `global USER_SETUP`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Still has the same unused variable warning, and then I also get an error in if USER_SETUP == message.author.id: saying undefined variable

Comment: Did you declare it global in the right place (= at the start of the function)?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare that you're using each global at the start of each function you use them in (or at least prior to reading from/assigning to them):

```
USER_DOING_SETUP = False
USER_SETUP = 0

@client.command(aliases=['rr', 'reactionroles'])
async def reactionrole(ctx, user, arg):
    global USER_DOING_SETUP
    global USER_SETUP
    if arg == "setup":
        if USER_DOING_SETUP == False:
            userId = user.id
            USER_SETUP = userId
            USER_DOING_SETUP = True
            await ctx.send(f"TEST REACTION ROLES TYPE {BOT_PREFIX}!rr cancel TO CANCEL")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Setup is used by another user")
    elif arg == "cancel":
        USER_DOING_SETUP = True
        USER_SETUP = 0
        await ctx.send("setup was cancled :)")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global USER_DOING_SETUP
    global USER_SETUP
    if message.author != client.user:
        if USER_DOING_SETUP == False:
            await message.channel.send("false")
        elif USER_DOING_SETUP == True:
            if USER_SETUP == message.author.id:
                await message.channel.send("true")
            else:
                await message.channel.send("false")
```